# Objects in texture and material view appear black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, texture-painting

I downloaded the .fbx file and used Principled BSDF for apply textures like in this video  https://youtu.be/9NjMeAFkm3s. Everything was okay (objects were been colored in *Texture and Material View*) until I reopened the .blend file.

**Problem:**

When I change from Solid to *Texture and Material View* my objects appear in black, but in *Render View* it still in color. When I choose *Texture Paint*, objects appear in white and I can not paint it (nothing happens). In UV/Image Editor the object has image and I can paint only the UV map (but object remains white in viewport).

I use Blendeer 2.79b and *Cycles Render*

**Attempts to solve**

- I have a light source
- I tried recalculating the normals
- I clicked ImageColorTexture in the Node Editor
- I checked out many solutions posted on the web

Also I have the same problem in another file.

**Attach my .blend files**

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ShUylwewaqJwfKHZEizU1Ht8FoBQq-xD?usp=sharing

*Originals from Sketchfab:*

- 1 file in the 1.blend:
  https://m.vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Fsketchfab.com%2F3d-models%2Freal-suit-for-ray-ii-retopo-3e543b8199f548cf99077c89929888b5
- 2 files in the 2.blend:
  https://m.vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Fsketchfab.com%2F3d-models%2Fleather-gloves-ad7e72b634354a2daafa09a6ae085a24

  https://m.vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Fsketchfab.com%2F3d-models%2Fblack-leather-glove-c954a6160ee34548a1b0ea538f3b92dd

Comment: I don't have 2.79b, but I have tried your files in later versions of blender and they seem to work fine.  Is it possible for you to upgrade your version of blender?  I'm using 2.93.1 but that's very different.  Can you at least upgrade to 2.83.16, which is the long term support (LTS) version of 2.8?  On the other hand, I looked at your shaders and as you have them they should work in 2.79b, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, my PC don't support the newer versions of Blender. But I solved the problem. I restarted my PC, opened my files and they worked fine. So I just think it was odd bug.